# Can someone tell me a sentence that sounds really angry involving cake

Tags: phrase-request, insult

I want to angrily call one of my friends a cake in a German sentence, but I don’t know German.

Comment: Don't know what exactly you are looking for but what comes into my mind is "Du gehst mir auf den Keks!" ("You annoy me", literally: you go on my cookie)

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify: Why you are looking for this? What exactly you are looking for? Is there a reason you expect such a phrase to exist? While the question is answerable as it stands in my opinion, you probably won’t get a helpful answer.

Comment: Creative porposal *verKUCHt nochmal* sounds quite similar to a well-known swearing phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Du hast nicht mehr alle Kerzen auf der Torte

is a variation of

> Du hast nicht mehr alle beisammen

Which means that he is losing an essential (mental) capacity (usually sanity or intelligence).

Side-notes:

- It might not be a very common expression (the base one is though)
- 'Torte' is a fancy version of a cake, which is literally translated to 'Kuchen'. But Torte has a more snotty sound in this sentance. Maybe because it is more posh.

Comment: This one will work for insulting my friend thank you

Answer (score -3):

One of my favorite phrases is

> Wenn der Kuchen spricht, haben die Krümel zu schweigen

which means

> When big daddy talks kids listen

Unfortunately its probably not what you are looking for, as you want to call your friend the cake not yourself ;)

But unfortunately for many and good for you there is a german (aggro-)rap subculture with tons and tons of slang expressions.

There you can find the word

> Kek

meaning [wimp, looser, etc](https://www.giga.de/extra/netzkultur/specials/was-heisst-kek-slang-begriff-aus-rap-und-co/)

Kek originates from a turkish cake: Topkek or kek. So it may be your best try. **But** unfortunately for you (again ;) ) Topkek or kek has a total different english meaning, as its a [intensification for lol](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=topkek).

Of cource you are allowed to make up words. German is very suitable for something like that.

You could call him a ..... [link](https://www.spreadshirt.de/spruch+tourette+beleidigung+maenner+premium+t-shirt-D5c17b31b2225093442752d04) (warning vulgar)